# PHP HTTP 500 error from mail() because message body contains the current host?

Tags: php, apache, email, freebsd

Given the following setup:

```
<?php
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "This is a test";
$body = "Login here: ";
?>
```

Enabling the following tests individually, these work:

```
<?php

mail($to, $subject, $body);

$bodytest = $body . "http://example.com"; 
mail($to, $subject, $bodytest);

$bodytest = $body . "http://CURRENTHOST.co"; // bad extension 
mail($to, $subject, $bodytest);

$bodytest = $body . "http:/currenthost.com"; // bad protocol
mail($to, $subject, $bodytest);

$bodytest = $body . "http:://currenthost.com"; // bad protocol
mail($to, $subject, $bodytest);
?>
```

Enabling the following tests individually, these each produce an HTTP 500 Internal server error:

```
<?php
$bodytest = $body . "http://currenthost.com"; // good root domain
mail($to, $subject, $bodytest);

$bodytest = $body . "http://www.currenthost.com"; // good subdomain
mail($to, $subject, $bodytest);

$bodytest = $body . "http://nonexistentsubdomain.currenthost.com"; // non-existent subdomain
mail($to, $subject, $bodytest);
?>
```

So something in the underlying system executed when calling mail() dies when the body contains a valid text url for the current host.  This is boggling my mind.

Searching the web gives a thousand unrelated PHP HTTP 500 errors associated with mail(), but nothing about the body containing the URL.

So I decided to post this question here.

The HTTP server is Apache 2.2 running on FreeBSD.

I've looked at the Apache logs, but there is nothing in them indicating the error.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I can't see how this is related to Apache config.

Comment: @SamPinkus The problem is an internal server error, HTTP 500... Sorry about that.  I will add HTTP to the SO question.

Comment: @SamPinkus I tagged Apache because this is using apache, it might have a better chance at being spotted by someone with greater awareness of apache servers, and similarly possibly FreeBSD ... in case this is an issue exclusively on that platform. Just trying to hit a moving and very difficult target.

Comment: Take a look at apache logs.also something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) might help.

Comment: @Himal thanks for your suggestion.  It is in fact PHPMailer in use on this server, that is also falling flat on its face because of this underlying bug.  I've looked for the logs... I've gone through /var/log/phperror and the /var/log/MYDOMAIN-access_log, where else may I find logs?

Comment: What you want is the error log, not the access log.try /var/log/httpd-error.log or /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: So just to be clear, it throws a 500 error if and only if you append a http address containing the sending domain to the body of the email? And it also does this when you try directly including it in $body rather than appending?

Comment: Not that it should matter here, but try replacing the double quotes around the url with single quote

Comment: @Himal okay thanks. I will check when I'm back at the dev machine. Currently getting a post-work strong drink to help the sanity.. :)

Comment: @WebChemist yes exclusively 500 for the sending domain. I am uncertain (have no access to) dns or wildcard subdomian host support. But arbitrary junk subdomains that are valid urls tigger this error. A friend of mine suggested it may be the smtp server that mail is connecting to, I may be triggering an anti-spam filter rule. So before I departed work I tried running the mail via php exec() and system() but no conclusion yet... :(

Comment: How do you know its a "HTTP 500 internal server error"? I dont get how HTTP is involved in this. Your talking about mail. SMTP. You should be looking at mail logs. If this is a Linux server running exim4 try `tail -F /var/log/exim4/mainlog`

Comment: Maybe wrap the mail call in a try/catch block and see if you can catch a php exception that might be triggering the apache error?

Comment: @Himal I have posted a potential answer, check it out and let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have determined the reason for internal server failure is the failure of mail().  I **have not found** the absolute core reason for the url in the message body causing the failure.

`mail()` is failing because the response code from sendmail is not 0 (EX_OK), rather is 69 (EX_UNAVAILABLE).  On a side note... I never looked into `<sysexits.h>` before today.. something new learned!

Following are the tests I used.
They begin with:

```
<?php
$messagebody = "Hopefuly this works.\r\nI am trying to see if this will send using\r\nthe command line through PHP\r\nLogin here: ";
$goodurl = "http://www.mywebsite.com";
?>
```

now the first pass, without the url:

```
<?php
file_put_contents("testmail.txt", $messagebody );
$command = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -v -t -i myemail@gmail.com < testmail.txt";

$lastline = exec($command, $output, $returnval);

echo "Command: $command\n\n";
echo "Last line: \n$lastline\n\n";
echo "Return val: " . $returnval. "\n\n";
echo "All lines: \n" . var_export($output, true). "\n\n";
?>
```

and the second pass, with the URL:

```
<?php
file_put_contents("testmail.txt", $messagebody . $goodurl );
$command = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -v -t -i myemail@gmail.com < testmail.txt";

$lastline = exec($command, $output, $returnval);

echo "Command: $command\n\n";
echo "Last line: \n$lastline\n\n";
echo "Return val: " . $returnval. "\n\n";
echo "All lines: \n" . var_export($output, true). "\n\n";
?>
```

an examination of the relevant outputs, including verbose lines from first and second passes (using placeholders):

Passing without the url:

```
Return val: 0

All lines: 
array( ...
20 => '>>> DATA',
21 => '250 Recipient <myemail@gmail.com> OK',
22 => '354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>',
23 => '>>> .',
24 => '250 Ok: queued as C19C41AEE4E6',
25 => 'myemail@gmail.com... Sent (Ok: queued as C19C41AEE4E6)',
26 => 'Closing connection to barracuda.hoster.com.',
27 => '>>> QUIT',
...
)
```

Failing with the url:

```
Return val: 69

All lines: 
array (
20 => '>>> DATA',
21 => '250 Recipient <myemail@gmail.com> OK',
22 => '354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>',
23 => '>>> .',
24 => '554 rejected due to spam content',
25 => '/web/mywebsite.com/dead.letter... Saved message in /web/mywebsite.com/dead.letter',
26 => 'Closing connection to barracuda.hoster.com.',
27 => '>>> QUIT',
...
)
```

I'm not familiar with spam filter systems.
This failure takes place in either the Barracuda spam firewall or in Google's message filters.

Without further insight, I'm calling it a day (really two days) and going back to the source of the email body and removing the URLs.  Any insightful thoughts about this comments would totally appreciated!

Here are a few other notes I found relating to this:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/PTpkPX9EFAU

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858?hl=en&ctx=mail&authuser=2&expand=5

Comment: Looks like we can't do anything from our side except, not to include the site url in the email body.you could use a different domain to redirect traffic to your original domain(URL forwarding).

Comment: @Himal turns out the sending domain was on Barracuda's blacklist... An inquiry is being made about why that was the case, as I'm new to this project and have no idea what was happening before.  But with luck, this question-answer may provide generic useful info to anyone who might be experiencing sendmail issues.